# Find the mean time/distance between duplicate lines

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file containing tens of thousands of lines containing duplicates. I want to find the mean time/distance between the duplicates in terms of line numbers.

For example: (where the first column is a line number)

```
1 string1
2 string2
3 string2
4 string1
5 string3
```

would give 2 (3 lines between the first pair of duplicates, 1 line between the second duplicate, divided by 2 since there are 2 duplicates).

Any ideas on how to approach this?

**EDIT**

```
Starting test!
32-bit hash: 0x995D9A6E
32-bit hash: 0xA27B264D
32-bit hash: 0x856ED0A5
32-bit hash: 0x3B83614D
32-bit hash: 0x23D92F43
32-bit hash: 0xA1D0BE63
32-bit hash: 0xB0BF66B6
32-bit hash: 0x968F7074
32-bit hash: 0x76F75FD1
32-bit hash: 0x76A51358
```

Comment: If you have 3 duplicate lines, what distances do you consider: 1-2, 1-3, 2-3?

Comment: I guess I'd treat them as two separate duplicates. The distances considered would be between the first and the second, then the second and the third.

Comment: Well, you first said that you consider the distance to the first occurrence only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using GNU awk:

```
$ cat a.txt 
string1
string2
string2
string1
string3

$ cat test.awk
{
    if($0 in lines) {
        distance += NR - lines[$0];
        ++count;
    }
    else {
        lines[$0] = NR;
    }
}
END {
    print distance / count;
}

$ awk -f test.awk < a.txt 
2
```

---

The above gives you the distance between the first occurrence of the line with the others. If you would like a distance between the next and the previous occurrences of the same line do:

```
    # ...
    if($0 in lines) {
        distance += NR - lines[$0];
        lines[$0] = NR; # <--- add this
        ++count;
    }
    # ...
```

Comment: I don't believe this works. I tested it with a file of the normal size but with only 2 duplicate lines (each repeated once) and manually calculated it.

Comment: @SamSong It works on the sample you provided. Post another sample.

Comment: Edited the question with a sample from the input. Is there a way to post the entire file?

Comment: You Sir, have been great help. Thank you.